# How to send wstring buffer to stdin of a child process?

Tags: c++, named-pipes

I'm having trouble writing a WString to the STDIN of a child process. If I have only acii character string (eg: @WSX3edc), the code works fine, but if it contains a non ascii character (eg: @WSX3edcß) it fails.

The child process is 7zr.exe (7Zip cmd line version). The input I'm writing to the STDIN is the password to extract the file.

```
// inject password
wPassword.append(password);
wPassword.append(L"\n"); \\For carriage return
...
DWORD dwBytesToWrite = wPassword.length()*sizeof(wchar_t);
DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
char szBuffer[1024] = "\0";
wcstombs(szBuffer, wPassword.c_str(),wcslen(wPassword.c_str())+1);
dwBytesToWrite = strlen(szBuffer);
if (!WriteFile(hInput, szBuffer, dwBytesToWrite, &dwBytesWritten, NULL)) {
    std::cout<<"write file failed"<<GetLastError()<<std::endl;
    goto Cleanup;
}
```

The writefile always succeed but some how the file extraction is not successful due to faulty password injecting mechanism.

Createprocess for this looks like : (si object has the STDIN and STDOUT streams set using a CreatePipe earlier)

```
if(!CreateProcess((LPWSTR)cmd, (LPWSTR)cmdArgs, NULL, NULL, TRUE, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
        NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)) {
         std::cout<<"7zr.exe process creation failed "<<GetLastError()<<std::endl;
         goto Cleanup;
}
```

Note : **7zr.exe works just fine with this particular password**, if we run it on command-line and paste this password. The extraction works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the narrow character set doesn't have the relevant password character, you can't use this approach. Instead find what option `7zr` has for specifying the password. I don't have an executable called `7zr` but I do have `7z`, and the command `7z | find /i "pass"` worked nicely.

---

In other news:

- The variable `dwBytesToWrite` is initialized with one value, only to be reassigned a few lines later, without having been used.
- `goto Cleanup` is generally ungood in C++. If you want guaranteed cleanup use a destructor (the technique called RAII, read up on it).
- Microsoft's Hungarian notation, with prefixes such as `sz` and `dw`, is generally an abomination. It once, in the 1980's, supported the help system in Microsoft's Programmer's Workbench. AFAIK that product hasn't existed the last 30 years or so.
- The C cast in `(LPWSTR)cmd` can easily introduce a bug. Use `const_cast` where you want to cast constness. Then it would be more clear that this cast is incorrect: you need a mutable buffer.
- Instead of reporting a failure to the standard output stream, via `std::cout`, consider using the standard error stream, via either `std::cerr` or `std::clog`. Better, don't do i/o at the place where a failure is detected, but throw an exception to let the calling code deal with it. The calling code can't remove output that's already, uh, output.

Comment: If we add the password to the command by itself using -p, This password can be seen on process explorer tools. This is a security concern. hence directly echoing to the stdin. 7zr.exe works just fine with this particular password, if we run it on command-line and paste this password. The extraction works fine.

Comment: The security concern should be a separate question. Please don't invalidate current answers by adding that requirement to the question. But I'll answer it here, since it's so simple: if someone has controlling access to a computer, all bets are off wrt. a malicious attacker. All that remains is to guard against ordinary users stumbling over the password and using it inadvertently,  breaking things. You can guard against that with a stern warning. Yep, that's one good answer. Because it's not really a security concern. Just like Microsoft UAC is an annoyance, not security but marketing.

Comment: Oh. Note that the command line is UTF-16 encoded. The standard input stream is usually assumed, by the application, to be Windows ANSI encoded. Where Windows ANSI is the codepage specified by the `GetACP` API funciton.

Comment: Thanks for that input! It worked after converting to OEM CP:
WideCharToMultiByte(CP_OEMCP, WC_COMPOSITECHECK|WC_NO_BEST_FIT_CHARS, wPassword.c_str(), -1, mbBuffer, sizeof(mbBuffer), NULL, NULL);

Answer (score 1):

`wcslen(wide)` returns the number of *wide characters* in its argument `wide` ([see](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/wide/wcslen)).

`wcstombs(narrow,wide,len)` writes no more than `len` *bytes* to `narrow` ([see](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/wcstombs)).

Now if we always had one wide character = one narrow character = one byte, it wouldn't have much sense to have two varieties of characters, would it?

As soon as you have a wide character that translates to more than one narrow character, there is undefined behaviour.

Since your `szBuffer` is of fixed size, you could just as well write

```
wcstombs(szBuffer, wPassword.c_str(), sizeof(szBuffer));
```

Comment: no luck. with the sizeof(szBuffer) modification. Also I didn't understand the undefined behavior, you mean we aren't supposed to attempt anything like this?

Comment: There is more than one problem in your code, I only pointed out one that the other answer doesn't mention.